# Оплата на сайте 2023 для самозанятых?

Tags: node.js

Подскажите актуальные варианты интеграции оплаты на сайте для самозанятых на текущий момент, где есть способ оплаты через sberpay ?

И желательно что бы ещё и интегрировать можно было на бэк написанный на node.js

Comment: юкасса к примеру... Это же даже гуглить не надо реклама этих сервисов сама вылазит

Comment: Забыл написать в вопросе - кроме ЮKassa